# What is the difference between active and passive isolation in gravitational wave detectors?

Tags: gravitational-wave-detectors

GWDs are very sensitive instruments on the ground. To reduce seismic noise, core and auxiliary optics in GWDs are suspended. There are two main suspension techniques. One is active isolation and the other is passive isolation. I don't know what the difference is between the two. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you understand ear plugs vs noise canceling ear buds?